# Midnight Commander is calling Seamonkey, but why?

Tags: linux, mc

Midnight commander, on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a `.html` file, calls Seamonkey. I can't find out why.

Of course, I checked the usual suspects:

- The extension files from MC's settings (both the user- and the system-wide versions).
- Checked the files in /etc/mc (`mc.ext` is calling `mozilla` for `html` files, but that starts `firefox`.
- Checked in `/usr/share/mc`
- Checked in `.config/mc`
- Though this shouldn't matter in a text window, I'm using XFCE, but preferred app for the browser is Firefox

*Some more tests*

- On an empty test.html file, nothing gets called.
- If I put `<html></html>` in the file, seamonkey starts.
- The global extension file does call a intermediary script `/usr/libexec/mc/ext.d` which calls `mozilla`, which (at least manually) starts `firefox` (not seamonkey).
- `grep -A3 '#.*html' ~/.config/mc/mc.ext` produces:

```
# html
regex/\.([hH][tT][mM][lL]?)$
    Open=/usr/libexec/mc/ext.d/web.sh open html
    View=%view{ascii} /usr/libexec/mc/ext.d/web.sh view html
```

In `web.sh`, the View action tries to call links, w3m and lynx. The Open action `if [ -n "mozilla" -a  -n "$DISPLAY"`  calls `mozilla`, which calls firefox.

- `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` says: `firefox.desktop`

Any suggestions where to continue looking would be appreciated!

Linux Slackware64-current, XFCE 4.12

**EDIT**
First, apologies for disappearing - 't was the end of the semester and loads of work grading papers, and other admin work!

Yesterday I looked at what I think now, might be a related issue. When pressing  on a image file in MC, it does not open the image viewer. I did the following:

- Start `strace mc 2> mc_log` and checked the log file for tries to open the view, and behold, I found this (the command is much longer, and I split it in separate lines):

```
    ...rt MC_EXT_ONLYTAGGED
       sh geeqie /root/doc/20100517_whirlpool.png > /dev/null 2>&1 &
       /bin/rm -f /tmp/mc-root/mcextGZX7U0\n", 408) = 408
```

I believe `sh geeqie` shouldn't work. Isn't there a `-c` missing?

Comment: I have never used Midnight Commander, but another place you should have a look at is `/etc/mailcap`. Notice that `seamonkey` may not be invoked directly, but via some wrapper (like those oxymoronic `sensible-thing` in Debian)

Comment: @user414777 I had done a search in the content in all files in /etc (recursive), so I guess it would have popped up. Thanks though.

Comment: @Quasímodo Cheers. "Did you check all them?" Well, evidently I didn't, but I did a full-text search in all files in the locations I mentioned (and some more). As far as I know, Slackware doesn't have things like `sensible-thing` (I've used it for 20+ years). If I could just trace it or something.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried simply `Open=firefox %f &`?